# What are some popular science books in chemistry?

Tags: books

I have been reading the books *The Elements* by Theodore Gray and *Stuff Matters* by Mark Miodownik, both being very popular chemistry science books. Are there some other easy-to-read, popular but scientifically accurate chemistry books available?

The answer to the question should not be "primarily opinion based", since "popular" can be measured.

Comment: Napoleon's Buttons by Penny Le Couteur and Jay Burreson.  Salt by Mark Kurlansky

Comment: *Molecules that Changed the World* by  K. C. Nicolaou

Comment: Oxygen by Nick Lane.

Answer (score 2):

1) Curiosity: How Science Became Interested in Everything
by Philip Ball
 (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13650233-curiosity)

2) Molecules: The Elements and the Architecture of Everything
by Theodore Gray, Nick Mann
(https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20729580-molecules)

Comment: Are you familiar with these books? What do you like about them? What topics do they cover? Why should the asker look into them?